# Scala 2: generic function that returns another generic function

Tags: scala

How can you return a generic function from another generic function?
This doesn't work

```scala
def gen1[A](a: A) = [B](b: B) => ???
```

But i don't want to define the second generic in the first function like this

```scala
def gen1[A, B](a: A) = (b: B) => ???
```

Is it possible?

Error here:

```
illegal start of simple expression
[error]   def gen1[A](a: A) = [B](b: B) => ???
[error]                       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

What I'm trying to do is the equivalent of dotty's:

```scala
def gen1 = [A] => (a: A) => [B] => (b: B) => (a, b)
```

But can't find documentation for it in scala 2

Comment: Have you tried? What error do you encounter? Try to specify the return type.

Comment: "But i don't want to define the second generic in the first function" why? Sounds a little bit like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Well what I'm asking for is "How to define a curried function that has a generic in the returned function without having to declare all the generics in the main function". I can find documentation on how to do it in dotty, but not scala 2. Don't really know what u are talking about with "xy problem"

Comment: The reason you can find it in dotty, but on in scala 2 is obviously because it exists in dotty, but does not in scala 2 :)
Because scala 2 is not dotty.

The definitive sign of an xy problem is a statement like "I know I can do X but I don't want to do it, because I want to do Y". You are fixated on what you think is a solution, that does not really solve anything. 

Having said that, you can do what you "want" in scala 2, I just have no idea _why_ you would want to do it: `def foo() = { def bar[B](b: B) = ??? ; bar _ }`

Comment: And why would you need to know why I have to do it? It's like saying that If I ask how to screw a screw I need to explain what I'm building. Makes no sense. Also your solution doesn't give the same result as dotty's one.
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QdcL9FZkRSKeZk1OXlyrvg
This will require Nothing as parameter in the returned function.

Comment: If it's not possible to do it in scala 2 just say it, no need to be this polemical. Why would asking the equivalent of a pattern from language a to language b, or v1 to v2 need an explanation of why I need it? If I asked how to implement HOF in scala would I need to explain why I need an HOF? Or if I ask how to implement the decorator pattern in scala would I need to explain why I need the decorator pattern?

Comment: @rockson because you need that to solve some problem, I doubt the feature you need to implement is just return a generic method. Understanding what is the meta-problem you are trying to solve would allow us to provide alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphic functions don't exist in Scala 2. What you can do to get a similar effect is define a custom class with a polymorphic `apply` method.

```scala
class Gen1PartiallyApplied[A](a: A){
  def apply[B](b: B) = ???
}
def gen1[A](a: A) = new Gen1PartiallyApplied(a)
```

```scala
gen1[Int](42)[String]("foo")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. No need to specify "WHY", either provide the alternative to Polymorphic functions or say that's not possible in scala 2 THat's it, don't know why people were running in circles. Thank you sir

Comment: @rockson sorry people wanted to help you instead of just saying _"is not possible"_ (which was actually said).